# MassTransit 3 How to send a message explicitly to the error queue

Tags: system.reactive, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit with Reactive Extensions to stream messages from the queue in batches. Since the behaviour isn't the same as a normal consumer I need to be able to send a message to the error queue if it fails an x number of times.

I've looked through the MassTransit source code and posted on the google groups and can't find an anwser.

Is this available on the ConsumeContext interface? Or is this even possible?

Here is my code. I've removed some of it to make it simpler.

```
_busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");

    });

    cfg.UseInMemoryScheduler();

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "customer_update_queue", e =>
    {
       var _observer = new ObservableObserver<ConsumeContext<Customer>>();

       _observer.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)).Subscribe(OnNext);

       e.Observer(_observer);       
   });
});


 private void OnNext(IList<ConsumeContext<Customer>> messages)
 {
    foreach (var consumeContext in messages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Content: " + consumeContext.Message.Content);

        if (consumeContext.Message.RetryCount > 3)
        {
            // I want to be able to send to the error queue     
            consumeContext.SendToErrorQueue()
        }
    }            
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work around by using the RabbitMQ client mixed with MassTransit. Since I can't throw an exception when using an Observable and therefore no error queue is created. I create it manually using the RabbitMQ client like below.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.HostName = "localhost";
factory.UserName = "guest";
factory.Password = "guest";

using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (IModel model = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        string exchangeName = "customer_update_queue_error";
        string queueName = "customer_update_queue_error";
        string routingKey = "";

        model.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Fanout);
        model.QueueDeclare(queueName, false, false, false, null);
        model.QueueBind(queueName, exchangeName, routingKey);
    }
}
```

The send part is to send it directly to the message queue if it fails an x amount of times like so.

```
consumeContext.Send(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/customer_update_queue_error"), consumeContext.Message);
```

Hopefully the batch feature will be implemented soon and I can use that instead.
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/800